# How can I access user data when authenticating with Zend_Auth_Adapter_Ldap

Tags: php, zend-framework, ldap

I am using Zend_Auth_Adapter_Ldap to authenticate users for my Zend Framework based intranet website. When authenticating users with Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable, I know that we can use getResultRowObject to access full data (table's row) of user, how can I access data while using Ldap authentication? At least if I get email address of the user, I can use it to perform a query on my database to fetch other data of the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the used Zend Framework Version. With Version 1.11.2 you can get the UserAccount Object with:

```
//get user, StdClass returned
$user = Zend_Auth_Adapter_Ldap::getAccountObject();
```

Or with an older Version (and with new version too):

```
// get LDAP Adapter and use it for an query 
// (authenticated with provided credentials)
$ldap = Zend_Auth_Adapter_Ldap::getLdap();
```